# password attribute not working in full screen keyboard in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have an app in portrait mode in the SonyEricsson XPERIA X10i Android 2.1. I have an Edit Text which has password attribute as true. But whenever I click on it, full screen keyboard comes. There anything I type, it doesn't come in password format.

I tried using half screen keyboard. But there the problem is, I have two edit box. Click on password then on keypad there should be a NEXT button to go to next Edit box. With half screen keyboard, 'Next' disappear.

Please help me friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the keyboard. Are you using another type of keyboard? try using inputType="textPassword", if it works on the emulator but not on your phone meaning it could be your phone's fault.

Are you using some kind of custom rom?

Comment: I had figured it out. Actually I am using hint in the xml code. Due to this the font of hint text differs due to password attribute. I had done some logic to correct it. Due to that password is not working in full screen keyboard. Any way...Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

if you have setted the password attribute through code, the setting is lost when the orientation is changed. This is because android recreate the views by default when the orientation is changed. To prevent recreation you can add

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

in your activity in your manifest